# How I can show HTML in Silverlight?

Tags: html, silverlight, browser

I need any free Silverlight control. Iframe it's not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout VectorLight's  [Html RichTextArea](http://www.vectorlight.net/silverlight/controls/html_richtextarea.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

For simple HTML you can use this one:

http://www.sharpgis.net/post/2010/09/15/Displaying-HTML-in-Silverlight.aspx